# How to create sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I'm sorry about this question but the more I think about this, the more I feel ignorant.

How can I, by hand, create a sequence of functions $(f_h)_h$, let's say in $L^2((01))$, coverging, under the $\left\lVert \cdot\right\rVert_{L^1}$ norm, to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, for example.

This specific example was meant to show that $L^2((0,1))$ is not closed in $L^1((0,1))$, but this question would like to be way general, as I find myself always in trouble in creating explicitely sequences of functions. I'd really like to see the method for which create sequences, rather than simply read a specific answer as it won't help me grow, I think.

Any solution, hint or reference would be much appreciate, thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot, since $1/x^2 \notin L^1((0,1))$.

Comment: Yeah you're obv right, I thought $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ and wrote another thing... thanks anyway, altough I don't think this question will ever have an answer unfortunately :/

Comment: I noticed that you haven't accepted any answers to any of your questions so far. If your queston has been answered, consider checking the tickmark to mark the question "answered". This removes the question from the "unanswered" queue and rewards the answerer with some reputation (and you as well!).

Comment: Dear @Servaes, don't worry, I was just sleeping due to the time zone: I've just log in into MSE, I'll read your answers and I'll ask if something is misterious.... but I promise I'll accept your answer, you have been so kind and patient!

Comment: @cupoftea Sorry for my impatience, the 200 daily reputation badge got within reach and got to me ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is an integrable function, let $f_h=f\mathbf 1\{\lvert f\rvert \leqslant h\}$; then $f_h\in\mathbb L^2$ and by dominated convergence, $f_h\to f$ in $L^1$.